# Problema al compilar un reporte de iReport en Netbeans

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Hola estoy tratando de generar un reporte con ireport en netbeans al cual le estoy cargando un scriptlet, cuando ejecuto el reporte para poderlo visualizar en netbeans me sale todo bien pero a la hora de compilar el reporte desde mi aplicación me aparece el siguiente error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class : com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:69)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:507)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:624)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1280)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
at GUI.Factura.generarFactura(Factura.java:109)
at GUI.Factura.jButton4ActionPerformed(Factura.java:1068)
at GUI.Factura.access$1100(Factura.java:55)
at GUI.Factura$11.actionPerformed(Factura.java:630)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:109)
... 49 more
```

Comment: Consulta si tienes la libreria de iReports en el proyecto?

Comment: Si, están todas las librerías necesarias, ya lo probé sin el scriptlet y me carga bien, pero necesariamente necesito cargar el scriptlet

Comment: El error es claro, la clase `ConvertToWord` no se encuentra en to CLASSPATH. Asegúrate de agregar el JAR que la contiene.

Comment: Si está agregada en el classpath, es por eso que digo que en el visualizador de ireport si me funciona pero cuando ya junto el reporte con mi aplicación de netbeans me aparece el error que muestro en la parte superior